# PDF image is 1.3 MB, but after removing text in Illustrator becomes ~35 Mb (still vector in PDF)

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, adobe-illustrator

I have created a figure for my scientific work using ggplot (an R package for plotting data). It's a scatterplot that contains ~25.000 data points in a normal x-y-style plot. Each data point has a border and a color fill. The output vector PDF is 1.3 Mb in size. Now, I would like to make some final adjustments regarding font size and text position and merge it with other panels in a bigger figure which I normally do in Illustrator. So I add/embed the scatterplot to the rest of my figures which nicely loads all elements correctly. However, when I then simply save this file as .ai or .pdf, the output will be more than ~30 Mb. How is it possible, that all elements are still preserved in the original (small) PDF, but after Illustrator it is inflated to much? It is critical for me to keep the file size small.

I tried many things, including different PDF exporting options in Illustrator and macOS Preview PDF file compression, but nothing worked. I even tried merging all those ~25.000 overlapping dots together in one or at least few shapes, but either Illustrator crashes in the process (Illustrator > Pathfinder unite/merge) or the resulting PDF shows some erratic behaviour, i.e. become black/white in Word (Illustrator > Flatten Transparency) What am I missing here?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Now, I would like to make some final adjustments regarding font size and text position and merge it with other panels in a bigger figure" I would do all of that in R with ggplot2 and gridExtra.

Comment: That's actually what I would prefer, but I also have some plots from other tools that need to be added. Those are also vector graphics inside PDF files, however I can't control the font size in those :(

Comment: I suspect your problem is that Illustrator does not embed the text as text but as curves.

Comment: Just a suggestion.... can't you read all _other images_ in `R` and merge your `scatterplot` in R itself, some packages for image processing are [imager](https://dahtah.github.io/imager/imager.html) and [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html)

Comment: @ Roland: I don't think that's the issue since the size stays that large even if I remove all text and only keep the plot itself.


@ Parth: I can see how that is for sure a possibility, on the other hand it seems like a lot of work when I really don't understand why it shouldn't be possible to the same with Illustrator. Since I need multiple text elements (also for axis labels), I think this would become quite complicated using R image processing tools :/

Answer (score 1):

When saving, make sure you're not enabling Illustrator editing capabilities. Leaving Illustrator editing capabilities enabled will essentially cause a copy of the Illustrator file (as an AI version) to be written into the PDF that's being saved. This often causes the PDF to increase dramatically in size, especially for files with many vector or path elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked was me was this:

1. Export as eps instead of pdf in ggplot. You *may* need to use `device=cairo_ps` as an option (I did).
2. In Adobe Illustrator, create a new document and select the web option
3. Combine all your figures into this new figure by dragging and dropping them there. Use "Embed" to embed those figures into the new one.
4. Make all changes you need
5. Save as pdf with default options (I used preset {Smallest File Size (PDF 1.6)}.

This preserved the small file size for me. I think the only thing that matters here is the use of **eps** instead of **pdf** when exporting from ggplot.